# Search for values apart from the letter case - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to enquiry companies' names. However, these names are provided all with UPPER CASE LETTER, while the data in the my database are mix (actual names). I tried to use `UPPER` function but it did not work as it does not take more than one argument.

```
SELECT company_name 
FROM   companies 
WHERE  companies IN UPPER( 'ABC', 'DEF', 'BDE', 'MNO' );
```

What options do I have to search apart from the strings letters case.
Values in the table have random upper/lower case names (e.g. 'aBc', 'Def' ... etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT company_name 
FROM   companies 
WHERE  UPPER(companies) IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'BDE', 'MNO');
```